# Flip an unfair coin

Tags: probability, probability-theory

An unfair coin has an probability of heads on a single flip $p=\frac 14$, the coin is flipped **n** times, and the probability of getting **2** heads is the same as the probability of getting **3** heads, what is the number **n**?

---

Thought process:
Initially I thought **p** is important and I set up $$np^2(1-p)^{(n-2)}=np^3(1-p)^{(n-3)}$$but it doesn't have a solution.
Then I thought about using Binomial Coefficient $${n \choose 2}={n \choose 3}$$, but then **p** is not used here at all.

Comment: The right way to proceed is to use a bit of both of your thoughts.  Do you know about the "binomial distribution"?

Comment: You need to substitute $\frac14$ for $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: The probability of $k$ heads in $n$ flips is
$$
\binom{n}{k}p^{k}\left(1-p\right)^{n-k}.
$$

**Details**: The probability of flipping $k$ **consecutive** heads first and **then** flipping $n-k$ **consecutive** tails is $p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$. This sequence can be written
$$
\overbrace{H\cdots H}^{k\text{ times}} \underbrace{T \cdots T}_{n-k\text{ times}}.
$$
There are $\binom{n}{k}$ ways to permute this sequence.

Comment: I see, using binomial distributions, $${n \choose 2}p^2(1-p)^{(n-2)}= {n \choose 3}p^3(1-p)^{(n-3)}$$, then solve for n.

Comment: @C.Cheng: correct. I added some details that may aid in your understanding of why this is the case.